# Set multiple fields as one element of oneof

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to define a message that can have 2 fields (field A AND field B) XOR one other field (field C alone). I saw I can use the keyword `oneof` to set the XOR, but only between two fields.
how can I express my needs?

Ideally I want something like (*not* working)

```
syntax = "proto3";

message M {
  oneof name {
    {
      string a = 1;
      string b = 2;
    }
    string c = 3;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to enforce an AND relationship like oneof is enforcing XOR one. Every field is optional in Protocol Buffers. So even if you go with @jpa answer, you will not be able to avoid developers using your `message A` wrongly (set only `a` for example). You'll have to  check that in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I know of is to put the two fields `a` and `b` into separate submessage, which you can then put inside the `oneof`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
    
message A {
    string a = 1;
    string b = 2;
}
    
message M {
    oneof name {
        A a = 1;
        string c = 3;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can put all fields into `M` without `oneof`. Describe the logic in the comments and check it manually in application code.